# Force All Windows To Open At A Set Resolution ('width x height' pixels)

Tags: unity, 12.10, window

Is it possible to force all application windows to open at a specific resolution (i.e. a set specific size like 1280x720 pixels)?

Comment: **[devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)** (cmd & gui) — Couldn't get it to work (hanged all windows and I had to restart PC via terminal), but something worth noting. Thanks to @fossfreedom for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it doesn't work very well.

- Install ccsm, `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` (note ccsm is pretty buggy).
- Start ccsm, go to the window management section
- Enable "Window Rules"
- In the options for "Window Rules", choose the "Size rules" tab
- Click new, then the +
- Choose your window (by class is usually best but it takes some experementing)
- Set your width and height.
- Apply everything and enjoy your fixed window heights.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful. All I see under window management section are: Grid, Move Window, Place Windows, Resize Window, Scale, Snapping Windows (and I checked then, and there seems to be no relevant option. I'll keep looking).

Comment: Hmm make sure you have the plugins installed. `sudo compiz-plugins-default`

Comment: [Screenshot 1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18875117/CompizConfig%20Settings%20Manager_034.png) [Screenshot 2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18875117/CompizConfig%20Settings%20Manager_035.png)

Comment: Terminal says, "compiz-plugins-default is already the newest version." But I still don't see the options that you are.

Comment: All I have from `dpkg --get-selections | grep comp` is compiz      install
compiz-core     install
compiz-gnome     install
compiz-plugins     install
compiz-plugins-default    install
compiz-plugins-main-default   install
compizconfig-backend-gconf   install
compizconfig-settings-manager   install

Comment: Here's what I got: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5T5a7.png - makes any sense?

Comment: Nope, looks like it's time for a new question: "What package installs the compiz plugin 'Window Rules'"