# Howto force all Windows to open not Maximized

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, compiz

i found some useful hints here:

i this answer from 2012 "Window Rules" is used
[Force All Windows To Open At A Set Resolution ('width x height' pixels)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223100/force-all-windows-to-open-at-a-set-resolution-width-x-height-pixels)
but i did not found "Window Rules" inside in the version from March 2021.

i tried use modified the answer here:
[How to configure my system so that all windows start maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized/135108#135108)

like so:

[image]

but Firefox still opens maximized.

## Motivation

When I drag the maximized windows a bit onto another monitor, they often suddenly snap to the top left corner, which I don't want.

And often the Windows is just to large.

## Operating System:

```
Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-34-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. ask ubuntu is a Q&A resource, I don't see any question here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it's not a question

Answer (score 0):

the settings of plasma can be overlaid by the individual apps and some start maximized. therefore e.g. the test with Firefox was unsuccessful. but had effect after using this Firefox addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-maximized-to-resizable/

I had previously set Cascade for new windows in 'Windows Managment'> 'Place Windows'> with ccsm. The tool turned off again. It looks like this rule is now in effect. I don't know it's coming from CCSM.